# String in Datum

Tags: plutus, plutustx

I want to use String or Text in a Datum, like this:

```
import PlutusTx.Prelude

newtype MyDatum = MyDatum {userReadableStuff :: BuiltinString}
PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData ''MyDatum
```

but the complier complains:

```
• No instance for (PlutusTx.IsData BuiltinString)
    arising from a use of ‘PlutusTx.fromBuiltinData’
• In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
    ‘PlutusTx.fromBuiltinData arg_a2lNn’
  In the second argument of ‘PlutusTx.Builtins.matchList’, namely
    ‘(pure MyDatum <*> PlutusTx.fromBuiltinData arg_a2lNn)’
  In the expression:
    ((PlutusTx.Builtins.matchList t_a2lNq)
       (pure MyDatum <*> PlutusTx.fromBuiltinData arg_a2lNn))
      (\ _ _ -> Nothing)typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)
• No instance for (PlutusTx.IsData BuiltinString)
    arising from a use of ‘PlutusTx.toBuiltinData’
• In the first argument of ‘PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.mkCons’, namely
    ‘(PlutusTx.toBuiltinData arg_a2lNi)’
  In the second argument of ‘PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.mkConstr’, namely
    ‘((PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.mkCons
         (PlutusTx.toBuiltinData arg_a2lNi))
        (PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.mkNilData
           PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.unitval))’
  In the expression:
    (PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.mkConstr 0)
      ((PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.mkCons
          (PlutusTx.toBuiltinData arg_a2lNi))
         (PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.mkNilData
            PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.unitval))typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)
• No instance for (PlutusTx.IsData BuiltinString)
    arising from a use of ‘PlutusTx.unsafeFromBuiltinData’
• In the first argument of ‘MyDatum’, namely
    ‘(PlutusTx.unsafeFromBuiltinData arg_a2lNv)’
  In the expression:
    MyDatum (PlutusTx.unsafeFromBuiltinData arg_a2lNv)
  In the expression:
    let
      t_a2lNy = PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.snd tup_a2lNu
      arg_a2lNv = PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.head t_a2lNy
    in MyDatum (PlutusTx.unsafeFromBuiltinData arg_a2lNv)typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)
```

I could use `ByteString` -- about which the compiler has no complaints, and then use helper functions for
`Text` <-> `ByteString`, as [shown at end of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357775/text-or-bytestring).  But what I really want is for end user to see the datum in the script, and be able to read directly from the datum.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you mean by "end user to see the datum in the script" and how having a `Text` or `String` in the datum would make any difference to this. Datums are not easily visible to everyone and certainly not to "end users".

However, if you want to use `BuiltinString` in `MyDatum`, you could write your own instances for `ToData`, `FromData` and `UnsafeFromData` via `BuiltinByteString` and `encodeUtf8`/`decodeUtf8` from `PlutusTx.Builtins`.

Something like the following could work:

```
instance ToData MyDatum where
  toBuiltinData = toBuiltinData . encodeUtf8 . userReadableStuff

instance FromData MyDatum where
  fromBuiltinData = MyDatum . decodeUtf8 <$> fromBuiltinData

instance UnsafeFromData MyDatum where
  unsafeFromBuiltinData = MyDatum . decodeUtf8 . unsafeFromBuiltinData
```

Note: I had a quick look at the implementation of the builtin `encodeUtf8`, this might not be what you expect (it seems to be currently ASCII encoding and truncating any code points outside of the 8bit range).